# ComponentWillMount undefined

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs, react-redux

morning guys, i am learning reactjs and trying to fetch admin lists data from api server that i have built using expressjs. well here is the case.

this is my reducer:

```js
import { FETCH_DATA } from '../actions/types';
const INITIAL_STATE = {};
export default function(state= INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_DATA :
            return {...state, payload: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

this is my action creator.

```js
export function getAllAdmin(){
    return (dispatch)=>{
        axios.get(`${Config.API_URL}/admin`)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_DATA,
                    payload: response.data
                });
                }
            )
            .catch(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
}
```

and this is my containers

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from 'actions/admin_action';


class Admin extends Component{
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.getAllAdmin()
    }
    renderData(){
        const admins = this.props.admin;
        console.log(admins.payload);
    }
  render(){
    
        return(
          <div>
            {this.renderData()}
          </div>
        )
  }
  
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { admin: state.admin }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Admin);
```

in renderData() function i do console.log(admins.payload) and show the result like below.

[the result of consoling log(admins.payload)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSF3D.png)

i am sure that "undefined" comes from the reducer for the first render it moves to default switch but i dont know how to solve this. because of the undefined i cannot map the result from my api server :(.

the question is how to solve this? i need your help. thanks!

Comment: Depending on how you've exported, you may just need `connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllAdmin })(Admin)`

Comment: i have done with connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllAdmin })(Admin), the undefined still appear. :(

Comment: Note that `{this.renderData}` doesn't call the function.

Comment: sorry, it called actually i type manually to this post. @Timo

Comment: Import it explicitly, e.g., `import { getAllAdmin } etc.` and make sure it's not undefined.

Comment: look at my reducer, i think something wrong in my reducer @DaveNewton

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
    case FETCH_DATA :
        return {...state, payload: action.payload };
```

should be:

```
    case FETCH_DATA :
        return {...state, admin: action.payload };
```

...and then, you shouldn't even be looking for .payload in your component. the payload was copied to state.admin in you reducer, which then gets populated into props.admin by redux's connect().

```
renderData(){
    const admins = this.props.admin;
    // console.log(admins.payload); <- don't need .payload here
    console.log(admins);
}
```

Comment: it's still the undefined appears, i dunno what happens in my app, everything seems good.. -_-

Answer (score -1):

if youre passing down props you need a

```
class Admin extends Component{    
    contructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }
```

Comment: gimme a little explanation, i ve use this but the undefined still appear. im sure it comes when i call my action creator.

Comment: hmm I may be wrong then. I actually see that you may not be passing down props. you're `importing * as actions` so perhaps try `actions.getAllAdmin()`

Comment: instead of this.props.getAllAdmin()

Comment: please look at my reducer, i think the undefined come from my reducer @CXNAJ